# Method for replacing the word

Tags: python

I want to replace the word in specific line in text file using python script.but also tried to get this using replace method.but this add the modified string to another line so please suggest me to get the output

Comment: you wan to save as another file ? or just show on the screen?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you need help please specify what have you tried and put some code. Thank you

Comment: Please consider supplying a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you have tried and what you would expect. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are more hints on how to ask a good question.

Comment: You probably want to look at `replace` and `split` for string

Answer (score 0):

```
from_file = open('/path/to/from_file', 'r')
to_file = open('/path/to/to_file', 'w')
string_to_replace = 'YOUR_STRING_TO_REPLACE' # make this your string
replacement_string = 'YOUR_REPLACEMENT_STRING' # make this your replacement string

for line in from_file:
    if string_to_replace in line:
        to_file.write(line.replace(string_to_replace, replacement_string))
    else:
        to_file.write(line)
```

Your output will be in whatever you name your `to_file` to be.